# Can't find any error in sklearn installation in ubuntu

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed scikit-learn using the command 'sudo apt-get install python-sklearn'. But I am getting ModuleNotFoundError. What is the problem in my installation?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn
from sklearn import linear_model
```

### Error showing below-

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

```
<ipython-input-3-413e8e9f65e9> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 3 import sklearn
      4 from sklearn import linear_model
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

Answer (score 1):

**`sklearn` module is not installed.**

Use:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

or conda:

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 0):

You should install sklearn by `pip`, meaning `pip install scikit-learn`

Comment: I am also using docker to open jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

Try creating venv by running "python3 -m venv namevenv", then activate the namevenv by running "source namevenv/bin/activate", then upgrade your pip with "pip install --upgrade pip", then try to force install sklearn within the virtual environemnt with "pip install --force-reinstall scikit-learn". Then you should be able to import sklearn if you work within the virtual namevenv environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as well. The solution I have found was to use
"sudo apt-get install python3-sklearn" instead, as it specifies to install the library for python3 (the one I was using), whereas I guess "sudo apt-get install python-sklearn is for pyhton2.
Hope this will help anyone else facing the same issue.